# TextDecorations Underline property — System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm doing a project with Xamarin, and when I try to add the `TextDecorations="Underline"` property to my Label, my IDE throws me a

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

PS: I'm using Xamarin.Prism, so I can't edit the **View.xaml.cs**.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="0" Padding="0,0,0,25">
    <Label Text="Vous êtes un nouveau lecteur? "/>
    <Label Text="Inscrivez-vous ici!" TextDecorations="Underline">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding SignUpCommand}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Exception stack trace is missing.

Comment: Please don't add tags to your question's title.

Answer (score -1):

What is the versions of your xamarin,Forms, I use the lastest Xamarin.Forms, and it can works fine. 
So I suggest you can update your xamarin.forms to the latest version and try it again.